# GCP/Python: Capturing actual error in subprocess.popen() while csv import from Hive to CloudSQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hive, subprocess, google-cloud-sql, popen

I have python 3.6.8 on GNU/Linux 3.10 on GCP and I'm trying to load data from Hive to CloudSQL.

```
        gc_cmd_import_csv_p1 = subprocess.Popen(['gcloud', 'sql', 'import', 'csv',
                                         '{}'.format(quote(cloudsql_instance)),
                                         '{}'.format(quote(load_csv_files)),
                                         '--database={}'.format(quote(cloudsql_db)),
                                         '--table={}'.format(quote(cloudsql_table_name)),
                                         '--user={}'.format(quote(db_user_name)),
                                         '--quiet'],
                                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                        universal_newlines=True)
    import_cmd_op, import_cmd_error = gc_cmd_import_csv_p1.communicate()
    import_cmd_return_code = gc_cmd_import_csv_p1.returncode
    if import_cmd_return_code:
        print("""[ERROR] Unable to import data from Hive to CloudSQL. 
        Error description: {}
        Error Code(s): {}
        Issue file name: {}
        """.format(import_cmd_error, import_cmd_return_code, load_csv_files))
        sys.exit(9)
print("[INFO] Data Import completed from HIVE to CloudSQL.")
```

In case of any error above, I'm getting message like:

```
Error description: ERROR: (gcloud.sql.import.csv) HTTPError 403: The client is not authorized to make this request.Error Code(s): 1
```

But when I actually run the same import command directly as shown below:

```
gcloud sql import csv test-cloud-sql-instance  gs://test-server-12345/app1/data/lookup_table/000000_0 --database=test_db --table=name_lookup --user=test_user --quiet
```

I'm getting the actual error like below:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.import.csv) [ERROR_RDBMS] ERROR:  extra data after last expected column CONTEXT:  COPY name_lookup, line 16902:
```

I want this message

> ( Extra data after last expected column... line 16902:)

to be shown in python script instead of

> HTTPError 403:

error. How to capture that?
Please note: There is no authentication issue as suggested by HTTP Error.

Answer (score 1):

So after long discussion with GCP Admin, we have found the issue.

We tried to execute the same import command using `os.system()` and then again we got the HTTP error. Admin then revisited the GCP IAM documentation and created a role for P-SQL user. Issue is resolved now.